# Lua: "error": "attempt to call method 'mouse_click' (a nil value)",

Tags: lua, scrapy, lua-table, scrapy-splash

I am new to Lua and trying to iterate over all the links from "items" by using "for" loop and click all the links using the mouse_click() function. But it throws **"error": "attempt to call method 'mouse_click' (a nil value)"** How can I do that? I have tried the below-mentioned code by myself but there may be something missing. From the documentation, I found that Lua has two types of for loop. Numeric and Generic. But to iterate through the links and after that click on it what I have to use?

Once again, I am very new to Lua. Just trying to get familiar with it so I am seeking all the experts' guidance.

```
function main(splash, args)
  
  splash:set_user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36")
  splash.private_mode_enabled = false
  assert(splash:go(args.url))
  assert(splash:wait(3))
  
  items = assert(splash:select("div.item-list-content a"))
  
  for item in pairs(items) do
    item:mouse_click()
    assert(splash:wait(5))
  end
  
  splash:set_viewport_full()
  return {
    html = splash:html(),
    png = splash:png(),
    har = splash:har(),
  }
end
```

## Output

```
{
    "error": 400,
    "type": "ScriptError",
    "description": "Error happened while executing Lua script",
    "info": {
        "source": "[string \"function main(splash, args)\r...\"]",
        "line_number": 11,
        "error": "attempt to call method 'mouse_click' (a nil value)",
        "type": "LUA_ERROR",
        "message": "Lua error: [string \"function main(splash, args)\r...\"]:11: attempt to call method 'mouse_click' (a nil value)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does it say that there's a function called `mouse_click`?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica sorry typing mistake. It's a method

Comment: Do you have the link to the website? It's easier to check against your code with it and to find improvements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Select` returns only *one* element, so it doesn't make sense to iterate over it using `pairs` (as you would be iterating over that element's fields, which is probably not what you want). You probably want to use `select_all` and then use ipairs to iterate over the elements that match the selector. See the [select](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripting-ref.html#splash-select) documentation for details and examples.

[Update to address your comment] If you look at the example I reference, you'll see that it looks like this:

```lua
    local imgs = splash:select_all('img')
    local srcs = {}

    for _, img in ipairs(imgs) do
      srcs[#srcs+1] = img.node.attributes.src
    end
```

As `ipairs` returns two values (index and its value), you'll have to use `for _, item in ipairs(items)` instead of `for item in ipairs(items)` (as in the latter case `item` will get index value instead of the item).

Comment: I used select_all and ipairs as you suggest but now it showing

{
    "error": 400,
    "type": "ScriptError",
    "description": "Error happened while executing Lua script",
    "info": {
        "source": "[string \"function main(splash, args)\r...\"]",
        "line_number": 11,
        "error": "attempt to index local 'item' (a number value)",
        "type": "LUA_ERROR",
        "message": "Lua error: [string \"function main(splash, args)\r...\"]:11: attempt to index local 'item' (a number value)"
    }
}

Comment: @RaisulIslam you cannot index number values. items is a list of number. so in your loop item is a number value and hence you cannot do item:mouse_click().  This is very basic Lua. Please read the manual and do a beginners tutorial if you cannot make sense of error messages like this. you have a line number, a variable name, its type and an operation that failed. what else could you wish for? you just need to think about that. what value do you expect? what is it instead? what do you need to change to fix it?